# Measuring degrees of randomness

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, random

Imagine, for simplicity's sake, that we have a set of numbers, each equal to either 0 or 1. Let's call each a bit. Rationally, if the set is completely random, and reasonably large, the probability should be quite high that each possible value (0 or 1) is equally represented, and this probability should grow with increasing size of the set, until, with infinite bits in the set, the chance each possible value is equally represented should be exactly 1.

However, with my current knowledge of set theory and statistics, I cannot think of a way to measure this probability, given a set size and number of contained values. Also, assuming we have found this function, it implicitly defines the set as perfectly random. If that were not so, how could one factor in "degree of randomness?" How is degree of randomness measured?

Comment: Caution: the probability that a (uniformly) random sequence of $2n$ bits has exactly $n$ zeroes and $n$ ones goes to $0$ (as $1/\sqrt{n}$), not to $1$, when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The law of large numbers dictates that if there are two possible bit values, with equal probability of occurring, as the number of bits in the set approaches infinity, the set should approach an equal proportion of each

Comment: Two caveats: a sequence can be perfectly random, yet have unequal probabilities of 0's and 1's (f.i. take a balanced sequence and multiply the bits in pairs, giving 75% of 0 and 25% of 1). On the other hand a sequence can be perfectly balanced (010101010101...) and not be random at all.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests

Comment: You should avoid speaking of "a set of numbers" as elements in a set 1. must be distinct 2. are not ordered. Sequence is much better.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Let's rephrase that. In a _sequence_ of items such that each item is just as likely to appear as any other (50/50 for two items, 25/25/25/25 for four, etc.), as the number of items grows to infinity, you'd expect the observed probabilities to progressively more closely match the expected probabilities. As such, with more cards in a deck, you'd expect the mix to more closely match 1/52 of the deck per card, more flips of a fair coin 1/2 of the flips per possibility (heads/tails) and so on

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist: "equiprobable events" is missing in your problem statement. And convergence to some value is no indication of randomness.

Answer (score 3):

The question came up while the first answer is perfect

I'll add a complement to the answer of this question : *How is degree of randomness measured?*

Instead of computing the variance of all the datas, that is in some cases intrinsically difficult, one can pick random samples, compute their variances and the variance of the sampled variances. In some cases when speed is critical, simply counting the number of bits up in small samples may give accurate informations on the quality of the whole set of the random datas.

This method may be used dynamically to build a confidence(time) curve that may be used in the real time ( or not ) analyses.

Comment: if this answer doesn't shock you, perhaps you will like this question [Randomly select k boxes and place a ball into the least-loaded one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891264/randomly-select-k-boxes-and-place-a-ball-into-the-least-loaded-one)

Answer (score 2):

You are interested in the proportion of $1$s in the set, that is $n/N$ where $N$ is the size of the set, and $n$ is the random number of $1$s.

Now $n$ is sum of independant Bernoulli variables $x_i$ with parameter $(p=1/2)$ and you are interested in the deviations from the mean $1/2$.

From the [CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) the size of the deviations is $\sqrt{N}$ for the number of $1$s, that is $\frac 1{\sqrt{N}}$ for the ratio:

$$
P\left(\left|\frac nN - \frac 12\right|>\frac a{\sqrt{N}}\right)=
P\left( \sqrt{N}\left|\frac 1N \sum x_i - Ex_1 \right|>a\right)\to
\int_{-a}^a \exp{-\frac{u^2}{2V}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{2\pi V}}
$$where $V=p(1-p)=1/4$ is the variance of the $x$ variable.