# Randomly select $k$ boxes and place a ball into the least-loaded one.

Tags: probability

1. Suppose we have $M$ balls and $N$ boxes.
2. Select $k$ boxes from the $N$ boxes at random, then place a ball into the least-loaded one among the $k$ boxes. In case of a tie, place the ball randomly among the tied boxes.
3. Repeat this process until all the balls have been placed.

Let $X$ denote the number of balls in a box, what is the distribution of $X$?

Comment: My guess at first sight is that the Euler Zigzag numbers (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerZigzagNumber.html) are involved.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OK, I will take a look.

Comment: @igael Randomly between the boxes in the tie. I have edit the question.

Comment: I'm working on a sub question ... but it's difficult :)

Comment: @igael yes, it's difficult. Good luck for both of us.

Comment: Is $k$ fixed? Or can it vary from ball to ball?

Comment: @paw88789 and all : I made simulations with k fixed to floor N/2 , N/3 and N/4 with misc values of N ( 12 to 48 ). Be sure to get an almost perfect uniform distribution, particularly if M is multiple of N and this even if M/N is small. The distribution converges quickly. Now, it remains to find a model to explain that stuff ...

Comment: @paw88789 k is fixed

Comment: @igael This result is exciting! Did you try more larger values for M and N? You may want to read these papers and their references: [1] Y. Azar, A. Z. Broder, A. R. Karlin, and E. Upfal, “Balanced allocations,”
in Proceedings of ACM STOC, 1994, pp. 593–602. [2]  B. Vöcking, “How asymmetry helps load balancing,” Journal of ACM,
vol. 50, no. 4, pp. 568–589, 2003 [3] M. Mitzenmacher, “Studying balanced allocations with differential equa-
tions,” Combinatorics, Probability and Computing, vol. 8, no. 05, pp.
473–482, 1999.

Comment: @Bloodmoon: do you want to see the simulation ? I wonder if it fits your question : are you interested by the efficiency of the way of equi-distribution ( then analysing a typical one, ie computing its variance ) or by a statistic on the distributions ( mean of distributions made by this way ) ? Finally I'm not sure that the latter has a great interest.

Comment: @igael Yes, I want to see it, please give me a link. And I think I am interested in the former one.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your answer ; I'll look for my 15 aug drafts quickly

Comment: @igael it's ok, no hurry.